# Remove all cart items from a button on a custom page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a bulk order form plugin (for use with wordpress/woocommerce) - all add to cart functionality is working fine. Where I am struggling is in creating a "Cancel Order" button which, when pressed, clears all item rows (this bit works) as well as removes all items from the cart.

I am attempting this using a combination of AJAX/js, php and standard HTML..:

My button..:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="cancelorder">Cancel Order</button>
```

My cart-empty function..:

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );

function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

and finally, my js function/ajax call..:

```
$("#cancelorder").click(function(){        
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all rows?')){
        $(".addedrow").remove(); //removes line items - not related to issue
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_clear_cart_url',
        data: {action : 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url'},
        success: function (res) {
            if (res) {
                alert('Removed Successfully');
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        //back out with no action
    }
});
```

Rows are removed from the form, but the items remain in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I was able to get this working by modifying the existing code above to the following..:

Cart-Empty function..:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url', 'wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url', 'wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url'); 
//added wc_ prefix in case of function name conflict

function wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;
$returned = ['status'=>'error','msg'=>'Your order could not be emptied'];
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
if ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {    
    $returned = ['status'=>'success','msg'=>'Your order has been reset!'];       
}
die(json_encode($returned));
}
```

and the js/ajax side..:

```
$("#cancelorder").on('click',function(){        
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all rows?')){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url',
        data: {action : 'wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url'},
        success: function (data) {
                if (data.status != 'success') {
                    alert(data.msg);
                } else {
                    $('#itemrows').html('');
                    addrows();
                }
            }   
        });
    } else {
        //back out with no action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you are sending a POST request

```
type: "POST"
```

and trying to recover a GET parameter on your controller

```
if ( isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) )
```

Plus, the key you're looking for (`'empty-cart'`) doesn't even seem to exist...
At least in this portion of code you provided...